# Swagger is not generating @Api resources

Tags: spring, jersey, swagger

I'm trying to integrate Swagger to document my REST API. I have followed this tutorial verbatim: http://jakubstas.com/spring-jersey-swagger-configuration/ and it works peroperly. I see:

```
{
    apiVersion: "1.0",
    swaggerVersion: "1.2"
}
```

Now, I want to register one endpoint:

```
@Path("endpoint")
@Api(value = "/endpoint", description = "My first documented endpoint")
public class MyEndpoint {
  //METHODS
}
```

But when I navigate to `api-doc` URL, it still returns the same:

```
{
    apiVersion: "1.0",
    swaggerVersion: "1.2"
}
```

My endpoint resource is inside the correct package. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. I have added an `@ApiOperation`on my @GET method and it is working now. It is needed at least one operation so that Swagger can document it.